# Mysterious lines in C#

Tags: c#

I came across this code:

```
// A
private readonly int value;
public int RawValue => value;

// B
public int CompareTo(Foo other) => value.CompareTo(other.value);

// C
internal int x => unchecked((value & y) + 1);
```

Could someone please explain what happened here and what are common ways for using those techniques?

**EDIT**
Link to the code: [click](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/a209e60a2a967f2e97f0692025e999eca4c7fa53/src/NodaTime/YearMonthDay.cs)

Comment: Seems like C# 6.0 syntax for methods explained by Mads Torgersen on Channel9. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/116

Comment: Even I am itching to downvote :)... but anyone care to explain why?

Comment: @HimBromBeere that depends on which compiler version you use...

Comment: "I came across this code". On a site where they explain the new C# 6 features?

Comment: @Dennis_E indeed; quite possibly with text explaining what A, B, and C denote ;p

Comment: No, on Jon Skeet's GitHub. This is a part of NodaTime

Comment: @CarbineCoder just added it

Comment: If you'd like to know more about C# 6: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14

Comment: Since that is Jon's code, you might find this article by Jon talking about these concepts *in this context* to be useful: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/12/08/c-6-in-action/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a C# 6 syntax of declaring properties (read-only ones) and methods using expression-bodied members (looks similar to lambda expressions).

```
public int RawValue => value;
```

is equivalent to

```
public int RawValue 
{
    get { return value; }
}
```

and

```
public int CompareTo(Foo other) => value.CompareTo(other.value);
```

is equivalent to

```
public int CompareTo(Foo other)
{
    return value.CompareTo(other.value);
}
```